# bash script terminal comands?

Tags: bash, vpn, openvpn

So I'm trying to write a script to open my vpn and add the passwords I tried the network manager but the only options I have to add a vpn is pptp which is strange? the app that they offer won't install it just starts installing then stops (the same with chrome)weird? So I figured I could write a simple script but I'm new to this and cant get it to work. The script looks as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal -e sudo openvpn --config '/home/jim/desktop>/my_expressvpn_switzerland_udp.ovpn'

gnome-terminal -e desktop password

gnome-terminal -e vpn username thingy

gnome-terminal -e vpn password
```

where have I gone wrong? any advice on sorting any of the above issues?

sorry about the format new here

Comment: first of all you don't need to open terminal in the script. the script is executed in terminal (silently in the background) by default. try your script without opening terminal. if that doesn't work, then edit the question to check it. 2nd: when using sudo in a script , you either set root privillages to the script either enter password. check google to find "execute sudo in a script"

Comment: Sorry I'm a complete newb you say I don't need to open the terminal? I've been running the script by droping it into terminal as if I double click it opens in vi and I'll look at the execute sudo in script. But if you could elaborate on the first bit I would apricate? Thanks

Comment: You want to use a library called expect. It will put in the information on screens it expects to appear.   [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393848/using-expect-in-bash-script

Comment: i meant that you don't need the command to open terminal in a script. gnome-terminal -e is just useless there. after you make the script and test that its working, you can copy it in /usr/bin and link to desktop or wherever you like. being in /usr/bin it means that you can type its name in terminal from any place and execute it. then you can also set a keyboard hortcut to execute it even easier.

Comment: Awesome that really helps so in a bash script if I want to do these commands I would just type the comand? I was thinking last night do I need to type run after each line to get it to click enter?

Comment: OK that's awesome so it should look like
>#!/bin/bash
>sudo openvpn --config '/home/jim/desktop>/my_expressvpn_switzerland_udp.ovpn'

>desktop password

>vpn username thingy

>vpn password
I'll have a play with taking the password out at a later date